# STL deque accessing by index is O(1)?

Tags: c++, stl, deque, random-access

I've read that accessing elements by position index can be done in constant time in a STL deque. As far as I know, elements in a deque may be stored in several non-contiguous locations, eliminating safe access through pointer arithmetic. For example:

abc->defghi->jkl->mnop

The elements of the deque above consists of a single character. The set of characters in one group indicate it is allocated in contiguous memory (e.g. abc is in a single block of memory, defhi is located in another block of memory, etc.). Can anyone explain how accessing by position index can be done in constant time, especially if the element to be accessed is in the second block? Or does a deque have a pointer to the group of blocks?

Update: Or is there any other common implementation for a deque?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found this deque implementation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue#Implementations):

> Storing contents in multiple smaller arrays, allocating additional
> arrays at the beginning or end as needed. Indexing is implemented by
> keeping a dynamic array containing pointers to each of the smaller
> arrays.

I guess it answers my question.

Comment: "_Indexing is implemented_" does not really explain how it is works.

Comment: If you have a list of equi-sized chunks (e.g. 10 slots per chunk) and a vector with pointers to each chunk, then if you want to look up the i'th element, you can first map that to the vector in constant time (divide by 10) and then follow the pointer to the chunk, and finally find the element in the chunk via `i % 10`. All in constant time.

Answer (score 19):

The datas in `deque` are stored by chuncks of fixed size vector, which are

pointered by a `map`(which is also a chunk of vector, but its size may change)

[image: deque internal structure]

The main part code of the `deque iterator` is as below:

```
/*
buff_size is the length of the chunk
*/
template <class T, size_t buff_size>
struct __deque_iterator{
    typedef __deque_iterator<T, buff_size>              iterator;
    typedef T**                                         map_pointer;

    // pointer to the chunk
    T* cur;       
    T* first;     // the begin of the chunk
    T* last;      // the end of the chunk

    //because the pointer may skip to other chunk
    //so this pointer to the map
    map_pointer node;    // pointer to the map
}
```

The main part code of the `deque` is as below:

```
/*
buff_size is the length of the chunk
*/
template<typename T, size_t buff_size = 0>
class deque{
    public:
        typedef T              value_type;
        typedef T&            reference;
        typedef T*            pointer;
        typedef __deque_iterator<T, buff_size> iterator;

        typedef size_t        size_type;
        typedef ptrdiff_t     difference_type;

    protected:
        typedef pointer*      map_pointer;

        // allocate memory for the chunk 
        typedef allocator<value_type> dataAllocator;

        // allocate memory for map 
        typedef allocator<pointer>    mapAllocator;

    private:
        //data members

        iterator start;
        iterator finish;

        map_pointer map;
        size_type   map_size;
}
```

Below i will give you the core code of `deque`, mainly about two parts:

1. iterator
2. How to Random access a `deque` realize

#### 1. iterator(`__deque_iterator`)

The main problem of iterator is, when ++, -- iterator, it may skip to other chunk(if it pointer to edge of chunk). For example, there are three data chunks: `chunk 1`,`chunk 2`,`chunk 3`.

The `pointer1` pointers to the begin of `chunk 2`, when operator `--pointer` it will pointer to the end of `chunk 1`, so as to the `pointer2`.

[image]

Below I will give the main function of `__deque_iterator`:

Firstly, skip to any chunk:

```
void set_node(map_pointer new_node){
    node = new_node;
    first = *new_node;
    last = first + chunk_size();
}
```

Note that, the `chunk_size()` function which compute the chunk size, you can think of it returns 8 for simplify here.

`operator*` get the data in the chunk

```
reference operator*()const{
    return *cur;
}
```

`operator++, --`

// prefix forms of increment

```
self& operator++(){
    ++cur;
    if (cur == last){      //if it reach the end of the chunk
        set_node(node + 1);//skip to the next chunk
        cur = first;
    }
    return *this;
}

// postfix forms of increment
self operator++(int){
    self tmp = *this;
    ++*this;//invoke prefix ++
    return tmp;
}
self& operator--(){
    if(cur == first){      // if it pointer to the begin of the chunk
        set_node(node - 1);//skip to the prev chunk
        cur = last;
    }
    --cur;
    return *this;
}

self operator--(int){
    self tmp = *this;
    --*this;
    return tmp;
}
```

**iterator skip n steps / random access**

```
self& operator+=(difference_type n){ // n can be postive or negative
    difference_type offset = n + (cur - first);
    if(offset >=0 && offset < difference_type(buffer_size())){
        // in the same chunk
        cur += n;
    }else{//not in the same chunk
        difference_type node_offset;
        if (offset > 0){
            node_offset = offset / difference_type(chunk_size());
        }else{
            node_offset = -((-offset - 1) / difference_type(chunk_size())) - 1 ;
        }
        // skip to the new chunk
        set_node(node + node_offset);
        // set new cur
        cur = first + (offset - node_offset * chunk_size());
    }

    return *this;
}

// skip n steps
self operator+(difference_type n)const{
    self tmp = *this;
    return tmp+= n; //reuse  operator +=
}

self& operator-=(difference_type n){
    return *this += -n; //reuse operator +=
}

self operator-(difference_type n)const{
    self tmp = *this;
    return tmp -= n; //reuse operator +=
}

// random access (iterator can skip n steps)
// invoke operator + ,operator *
reference operator[](difference_type n)const{
    return *(*this + n);
}
```

#### 2. Random access `deque` elements

common function of `deque`

```
iterator begin(){return start;}
iterator end(){return finish;}

reference front(){
    //invoke __deque_iterator operator*
    // return start's member *cur
    return *start;
}

reference back(){
    // cna't use *finish
    iterator tmp = finish;
    --tmp; 
    return *tmp; //return finish's  *cur
}

reference operator[](size_type n){
    //random access, use __deque_iterator operator[]
    return start[n];
}
```

You also see this question which give the main code of `deque`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50959796/6329006

Comment: Thanks but I'm still a bit confused how `.at()` is O(1), iterating over chunks doesn't seem like it is to me?

Comment: Is the code from a particular stdlib, or your own?  Is it published anywhere, ideally with tests to see it in action? :-)

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible implementation can be a dynamic array of const-sized arrays; such a const-sized array can be added to either end when more space is needed. All the arrays are full except, maybe, for the first and the last ones which can be partly empty. That means knowing the size of each array and the number of the elements used in the first array one can easily find a position of an element by index.
http://cpp-tip-of-the-day.blogspot.ru/2013/11/how-is-stddeque-implemented.html

Answer (score -1):

If deque is implemented as a [ring buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) on top of `std::vector`, which reallocates itself when it grows in size, then accessing by index is indeed O(1).

The standard provides evidence that such implementation was meant--at least it conforms to standard in complexity estimations.  Clauses 23.2.1.3/4 and 23.2.1.3/5 require that

- inserting to the beginning or to the end of a deque require constant time, while insertion to the middle requires linear time of deque's size
- when erasing elements from the deque, it may call as many assignment operators, as the distance from the elements being erased to the end of the deque is.

And, of course, you should count on standard requirements instead of your own vision on how containers and algorithms could be implemented.

**NOTE** that the standard requires more than these two points listed above.  It also poses requirement that the references to elements must stay valid between insertions to the back or front of the deque.  This can be satisfied if the ring buffer contains pointers to the actual elements rather than the elements themselves.  Anyway, my answer just demonstrates the idea that multiple implementations may satisfy certain requirements.

Comment: In this case, elements are allocated contiguously right... but I'm wondering what if it is not implemented as a circular buffer.

Comment: @jasonline, no matter how it's implemented, its behavior is governed by the C++ standard document.  It contains requirements that random-accessing the deque is fast, so an STL implementation can't be implemented the way you proposed.  I just outlined the way it can be implemented to comply to the standard.

Comment: @jasonline: A ring buffer does not guarentee contiguously allocated elements. The memory that they are sorted in is contiguous, but if the elements start at postion 987 and end at position 5 (and the ring buffer has space for 1000 things), then they are not contiguous.

Comment: You are wrong. It can't be implemented on top of std::vector because std::deque NEVER invalidates references to elements. But std::vector MUST when there is no free space.

Comment: "_If deque is implemented as a ring buffer_" deque is **not** implemented as a ring buffer.

Comment: Are you downvoting  people the same folks, who upvoted `Each chunk is a vector, and the queue (“map” in the graphic below) of chunks itself is also a vector.` at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6292437/110118 ? :)