# What really is a deque in STL?

Tags: c++, stl, deque

I was looking at STL containers and trying to figure what they really are (i.e. the data structure used), and the *deque* stopped me: I thought at first that it was a double linked list, which would allow insertion and deletion from both ends in constant time, but I am troubled by [the promise made](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/operator_at) by the operator [] to be done in constant time. In a linked list, arbitrary access should be O(n), right?

And if it's a dynamic array, how can it [add elements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/push_back) in constant time? It should be mentioned  that reallocation may happen, and that O(1) is an amortized cost, [like for a vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

So I wonder what is this structure that allows arbitrary access in constant time, and at the same time never needs to be moved to a new bigger place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [STL deque accessing by index is O(1)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297164/stl-deque-accessing-by-index-is-o1)

Comment: @Graham “dequeue” is another common name for “deque”. I have still approved the edit since “deque” is usually the canonical name.

Comment: @Konrad Thanks. The question was specifically about the C++ STL deque, which uses the shorter spelling.

Comment: `deque` stands for *double ended queue*, though obviously the stringent requirement of O(1) access to middle elements is particular to C++

Answer (score 249, accepted):

A deque is somewhat recursively defined: internally it maintains a double-ended queue of *chunks* of fixed size. Each chunk is a vector, and the queue (“map” in the graphic below) of chunks itself is also a vector.

[image: schematic of the memory layout of a deque]

There’s a great analysis of the performance characteristics and how it compares to the `vector` over at [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5425/An-In-Depth-Study-of-the-STL-Deque-Container).

The GCC standard library implementation internally uses a `T**` to represent the map. Each data block is a `T*` which is allocated with some fixed size `__deque_buf_size` (which depends on `sizeof(T)`).

Comment: That is the definition of a deque as I learned it, but this way, it can't guarantee constant time access, so there must be something missing.

Comment: @stefaanv True, the constant-time access is a lie. Or rather, there’s a trade-off: you can use a vector of (pointers to) vectors instead of the doubly-linked list to get constant-time access but you strictly speaking no longer have constant-time `push_front`. Or you could use the linked list and compromise the indexing runtime. In practice this will *still* behave indistinguishably from constant time because the number of data blocks is expected to be very small.

Comment: @Konrad, thanks, that confirms what I was guessing.  Still, in the implementation that I saw a while ago, the chunk size was either 512 bytes or the size of the entry, so the number of data blocks could be bigger than expected.

Comment: @stefaanv, @Konrad: C++ implementations I have seen used an array of pointers to fixed-size arrays. This effectively means that push_front and push_back are not really constant-times, but with smart growing factors, you still get amortized constant times though, so O(1) is not so erroneous, and in practice it's faster than vector because you're swapping single pointers rather than whole objects (and less pointers than objects).

Comment: Constant-time access is still possible. Just, if you need to allocate a new block in the front, push back a new pointer on the main vector and shift all pointers.

Comment: then you could use a circular buffer for pointers to avoid some pain if a lot of elements are added in front.

Comment: If the map (the queue itself) was a double-ended list, I don't see how it could allow O(1) random access. It might be implemented as a circular buffer, which would allow the circular buffer resizing to be more efficient: Only copy the pointers instead of all elements in the queue. Still that's a small benefit it seems.

Comment: @Wernight True, that part of my anwswer is utter nonsense, and a lot of the discussion in the comments is misguided. A deque is a vector of vectors, pure and simple (in fact, the stdlibc++ implementation has it simply as a `T**`). I’ve fixed that part.

Comment: I am wondering what happens when you call shrink_to_fit(), does it merge all (the middle) blocks into 1 (3) block(s)? This would be a logical step to ensure data locality, wouldn't it?

Comment: @leden The standard doesn’t specify anything in that regard. However, its complexity requirement is given as linear, so this would be allowed. I haven’t checked how actual implementations do this.

Comment: If this is really the implementation, then it doesn't have a constant time guarantee for *any* of the basic operations that I can see. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @JeremyWest Why not? Indexed access goes to the i%B-th element in the i/B-th block (B = block size), that’s clearly O(1). You can add a new block in amortised O(1), hence adding elements is amortised O(1) at the end. Adding a new element at the beginning is O(1) unless a new block needs to be added. Adding a new block at the beginning is not O(1), true, it’s O(N) but in reality it has a very small constant factor since you only need to move N/B pointers rather than N elements.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for the clarification. I was under the impression (perhaps from the word *recursive*) that the structure was more like a B+ tree, where the index block was a fixed size and more layers were added as needed. But this seems pretty reasonable. Although a lot of `push_front`'s could potentially be expensive...? I wonder why they don't use two vectors: one to add blocks on the front, another to add blocks on the end? Maybe the improvement doesn't justify the complexity.

Comment: Adding a new block at the beginning can be amortized O(1) if you keep a pointer to the first valid block, and every reallocation of the outer level vector leaves empty space at both the beginning and end of the allocated block. A standard `vector` doesn't do this but it's not a difficult modification.

Comment: Apparently, this implementation is also called a tiered array.

Comment: I am curious if an implementation uses the data structures in your graph.  Erasing `data[1]` will shift `data[0]` downward and `begin()` points to the new memory location of `data[0]`?

Comment: I still wonder why `std::deque::push_back()` is `O(1)` given that a chuck of memory might be allocated.  Thanks.

Comment: @HCSF Allocating a chunk *is* O(1) since its size is constant. But what’s more, even allocating variable-sized chunks (of size *m*, say) can be amortised O(1), if it only happens once every 1 / *m* operations.

Comment: I couldn't wrap my head around why `push_front` and `push_back` is O(1) instead of *amortized* O(1) given that when the first level list is full we need to reallocate and move the pointers. Turns out it's not counted according to the standard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46543078/6306190

Comment: @johan As far as I remember the standard wording you refer to has been added after the fact and is, frankly, disingenuous since it’s contrary to how complexity analysis is usually performed and is misleading.

Answer (score 52):

From overview, you can think `deque` as a `double-ended queue`

[image: deque overview]

The datas in `deque` are stored by chuncks of fixed size vector, which are

pointered by a `map`(which is also a chunk of vector, but its size may change)

[image: deque internal structure]

The main part code of the `deque iterator` is as below:

```
/*
buff_size is the length of the chunk
*/
template <class T, size_t buff_size>
struct __deque_iterator{
    typedef __deque_iterator<T, buff_size>              iterator;
    typedef T**                                         map_pointer;

    // pointer to the chunk
    T* cur;       
    T* first;     // the begin of the chunk
    T* last;      // the end of the chunk

    //because the pointer may skip to other chunk
    //so this pointer to the map
    map_pointer node;    // pointer to the map
}
```

The main part code of the `deque` is as below:

```
/*
buff_size is the length of the chunk
*/
template<typename T, size_t buff_size = 0>
class deque{
    public:
        typedef T              value_type;
        typedef T&            reference;
        typedef T*            pointer;
        typedef __deque_iterator<T, buff_size> iterator;

        typedef size_t        size_type;
        typedef ptrdiff_t     difference_type;

    protected:
        typedef pointer*      map_pointer;

        // allocate memory for the chunk 
        typedef allocator<value_type> dataAllocator;

        // allocate memory for map 
        typedef allocator<pointer>    mapAllocator;

    private:
        //data members

        iterator start;
        iterator finish;

        map_pointer map;
        size_type   map_size;
}
```

Below i will give you the core code of `deque`, mainly about three parts:

1. iterator
2. How to construct a `deque`

#### 1. iterator(`__deque_iterator`)

The main problem of iterator is, when ++, -- iterator, it may skip to other chunk(if it pointer to edge of chunk). For example, there are three data chunks: `chunk 1`,`chunk 2`,`chunk 3`.

The `pointer1` pointers to the begin of `chunk 2`, when operator `--pointer` it will pointer to the end of `chunk 1`, so as to the `pointer2`.

[image]

Below I will give the main function of `__deque_iterator`:

Firstly, skip to any chunk:

```
void set_node(map_pointer new_node){
    node = new_node;
    first = *new_node;
    last = first + chunk_size();
}
```

Note that, the `chunk_size()` function which compute the chunk size, you can think of it returns 8 for simplify here.

`operator*` get the data in the chunk

```
reference operator*()const{
    return *cur;
}
```

`operator++, --`

// prefix forms of increment

```
self& operator++(){
    ++cur;
    if (cur == last){      //if it reach the end of the chunk
        set_node(node + 1);//skip to the next chunk
        cur = first;
    }
    return *this;
}

// postfix forms of increment
self operator++(int){
    self tmp = *this;
    ++*this;//invoke prefix ++
    return tmp;
}
self& operator--(){
    if(cur == first){      // if it pointer to the begin of the chunk
        set_node(node - 1);//skip to the prev chunk
        cur = last;
    }
    --cur;
    return *this;
}

self operator--(int){
    self tmp = *this;
    --*this;
    return tmp;
}
```

**iterator skip n steps / random access**

```
self& operator+=(difference_type n){ // n can be postive or negative
    difference_type offset = n + (cur - first);
    if(offset >=0 && offset < difference_type(buffer_size())){
        // in the same chunk
        cur += n;
    }else{//not in the same chunk
        difference_type node_offset;
        if (offset > 0){
            node_offset = offset / difference_type(chunk_size());
        }else{
            node_offset = -((-offset - 1) / difference_type(chunk_size())) - 1 ;
        }
        // skip to the new chunk
        set_node(node + node_offset);
        // set new cur
        cur = first + (offset - node_offset * chunk_size());
    }

    return *this;
}

// skip n steps
self operator+(difference_type n)const{
    self tmp = *this;
    return tmp+= n; //reuse  operator +=
}

self& operator-=(difference_type n){
    return *this += -n; //reuse operator +=
}

self operator-(difference_type n)const{
    self tmp = *this;
    return tmp -= n; //reuse operator +=
}

// random access (iterator can skip n steps)
// invoke operator + ,operator *
reference operator[](difference_type n)const{
    return *(*this + n);
}
```

#### 2. How to construct a `deque`

common function of `deque`

```
iterator begin(){return start;}
iterator end(){return finish;}

reference front(){
    //invoke __deque_iterator operator*
    // return start's member *cur
    return *start;
}

reference back(){
    // cna't use *finish
    iterator tmp = finish;
    --tmp; 
    return *tmp; //return finish's  *cur
}

reference operator[](size_type n){
    //random access, use __deque_iterator operator[]
    return start[n];
}


template<typename T, size_t buff_size>
deque<T, buff_size>::deque(size_t n, const value_type& value){
    fill_initialize(n, value);
}

template<typename T, size_t buff_size>
void deque<T, buff_size>::fill_initialize(size_t n, const value_type& value){
    // allocate memory for map and chunk
    // initialize pointer
    create_map_and_nodes(n);

    // initialize value for the chunks
    for (map_pointer cur = start.node; cur < finish.node; ++cur) {
        initialized_fill_n(*cur, chunk_size(), value);
    }

    // the end chunk may have space node, which don't need have initialize value
    initialized_fill_n(finish.first, finish.cur - finish.first, value);
}

template<typename T, size_t buff_size>
void deque<T, buff_size>::create_map_and_nodes(size_t num_elements){
    // the needed map node = (elements nums / chunk length) + 1
    size_type num_nodes = num_elements / chunk_size() + 1;

    // map node num。min num is  8 ，max num is "needed size + 2"
    map_size = std::max(8, num_nodes + 2);
    // allocate map array
    map = mapAllocator::allocate(map_size);

    // tmp_start，tmp_finish poniters to the center range of map
    map_pointer tmp_start  = map + (map_size - num_nodes) / 2;
    map_pointer tmp_finish = tmp_start + num_nodes - 1;

    // allocate memory for the chunk pointered by map node
    for (map_pointer cur = tmp_start; cur <= tmp_finish; ++cur) {
        *cur = dataAllocator::allocate(chunk_size());
    }

    // set start and end iterator
    start.set_node(tmp_start);
    start.cur = start.first;

    finish.set_node(tmp_finish);
    finish.cur = finish.first + num_elements % chunk_size();
}
```

Let's assume `i_deque` has 20 int elements `0~19` whose chunk size is 8, and now push_back 3 elements (0, 1, 2) to `i_deque`:

```
i_deque.push_back(0);
i_deque.push_back(1);
i_deque.push_back(2);
```

It's internal  structure like below:

[image]

Then push_back again, it will invoke allocate new chunk:

```
push_back(3)
```

[image]

If we `push_front`, it will allocate new chunk before the prev `start`

[image]

Note when `push_back` element into deque, if all the maps and chunks are filled, it will cause allocate new map, and adjust chunks.But the above code may be enough for you to understand `deque`.

Comment: You mentioned, "Note when push_back element into deque, if all the maps and chunks are filled, it will cause allocate new map, and adjust chunks".  I wonder why C++ standard says "[26.3.8.4.3] Inserting a single element either at the beginning or end of a deque always takes constant time" in N4713.  Allocating a chuck of data takes more than a constant time.  No?

Comment: @HCSF It takes constant time because the time required to allocate the chunk is ~the same independently of the number of elements in the container. Even spending more time than an allocation of a single element it still continues to be constant.

Comment: Is the code from a particular stdlib, or your own?  Is it published anywhere, ideally with tests to see it in action? :-)

Comment: @lucas.exe, When the map is reallocated, the work scales with the total capacity of the map i.e. map_len = capacity / chunk_len.

Comment: @HCSF, not always constant, but amortized constant. Big difference. Something that has good amortized complexity can still have a bad worst case on any particular call.

Comment: @underscore_d public available as STL designed around template-based programming generic enough for all types, and at compile time. On linux, look at `/usr/include/c++/<version>`, you can grep the code, or index the whole STL lib with `ctags` there for ease of searching. Anyhow for this particular of `std::deque`, it locates at `/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_deque.h`. In case it makes call to functions that is not available from header files, you would have to look into gcc source code itself.

Comment: @haxpor Yeah, I'm aware what the stdlib is; my point was just that it would be good if when writing an answer that lifts blobs of code, to include a link/citation to the source.

Comment: @underscore_d fair enough, yeah I've looked into header files of STL a lot to not think in perspective of someone else. I thought it's organic and natural enough. But yeah that is a good point also.

Answer (score 28):

Imagine it as a vector of vectors. Only they aren't standard `std::vector`s.

The outer vector contains pointers to the inner vectors. When its capacity is changed via reallocation, rather than allocating all of the empty space to the end as `std::vector` does, it splits the empty space to equal parts at the beginning and the end of the vector. This allows `push_front` and `push_back` on this vector to both occur in amortized O(1) time.

The inner vector behavior needs to change depending on whether it's at the front or the back of the `deque`. At the back it can behave as a standard `std::vector` where it grows at the end, and `push_back` occurs in O(1) time. At the front it needs to do the opposite, growing at the beginning with each `push_front`. In practice this is easily achieved by adding a pointer to the front element and the direction of growth along with the size. With this simple modification `push_front` can also be O(1) time.

Access to any element requires offsetting and dividing to the proper outer vector index which occurs in O(1), and indexing into the inner vector which is also O(1). This assumes that the inner vectors are all fixed size, except for the ones at the beginning or the end of the `deque`.

Comment: You can describe the inner vectors as having fixed *capacity*

Answer (score 21):

(This is an answer I've given in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8632350/146041). Essentially I'm arguing that even fairly naive implementations, using a single `vector`, conform to the requirements of "constant non-amortized push_{front,back}". You might be surprised, and think this is impossible, but I have found other relevant quotes in the standard that define the context in a surprising way. Please bear with me; if I have made a mistake in this answer, it would be very helpful to identify which things I have said correctly and where my logic has broken down. )

In this answer, I am not trying to identify a *good* implementation, I'm merely trying to help us to interpret the complexity requirements in the C++ standard. I'm quoting from [N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf), which is, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B1x), the latest freely available C++11 standardization document. (It appears to be organized differently from the final standard, and hence I won't quote the exact page numbers. Of course, these rules might have changed in the final standard, but I don't think that has happened.)

A `deque<T>` could be implemented correctly by using a `vector<T*>`. All the elements are copied onto the heap and the pointers stored in a vector. (More on the vector later).

Why `T*` instead of `T`? Because the standard requires that

> "An insertion at either end of the deque invalidates all the iterators
>   to the deque, but has *no effect on the validity of references to
>   elements of the deque.*"

(my emphasis). The `T*` helps to satisfy that. It also helps us to satisfy this:

> "Inserting a single element either at the beginning or end of a deque always  ..... causes a *single call to a constructor of T*."

Now for the (controversial) bit. Why use a `vector` to store the `T*`? It gives us random access, which is a good start. Let's forget about the complexity of vector for a moment and build up to this carefully:

The standard talks about "the number of operations on the contained objects.". For `deque::push_front` this is clearly 1 because exactly one `T` object is constructed and zero of the existing `T` objects are read or scanned in any way. This number, 1, is clearly a constant and is independent of the number of objects currently in the deque. This allows us to say that:

'For our `deque::push_front`, the number of operations on the contained objects (the Ts) is fixed and is independent of the number of objects already in the deque.'

Of course, the number of operations on the `T*` will not be so well-behaved. When the `vector<T*>` grows too big, it'll be realloced and many `T*`s will be copied around. So yes, the number of operations on the `T*` will vary wildly, but the number of operations on `T` will not be affected.

Why do we care about this distinction between counting operations on `T` and counting operations on `T*`? It's because the standard says:

> All of the complexity requirements in this clause are stated solely in terms of the number of operations on the contained objects.

For the `deque`, the contained objects are the `T`, not the `T*`, meaning we can ignore any operation which copies (or reallocs) a `T*`.

I haven't said much about how a vector would behave in a deque. Perhaps we would interpret it as a circular buffer (with the vector always taking up its maximum `capacity()`, and then realloc everything into a bigger buffer when the vector is full. The details don't matter.

In the last few paragraphs, we have analyzed `deque::push_front` and the relationship between the number of objects in the deque already and the number of operations performed by push_front on contained `T`-objects. And we found they were independent of each other. **As the standard mandates that complexity is in terms of operations-on-`T`, then we can say this has constant complexity.**

Yes, the **Operations-On-T*-Complexity** is amortized (due to the `vector`), but we're only interested in the **Operations-On-T-Complexity** and this is constant (non-amortized).

The complexity of vector::push_back or vector::push_front is irrelevant in this implementation; those considerations involve operations on `T*` and hence are irrelevant. If the standard was referring to the 'conventional' theoretical notion of complexity, then they wouldn't have explicitly restricted themselves to the "number of operations on the contained objects". Am I overinterpreting that sentence?

Comment: It seems a lot like cheating to me ! When you specify the complexity of an operation, you don't do it on some part of the data only : you want to have an idea of the expected runtime of the operation you are calling, regardless of what it operates on.
If I follow your logic about operations on T, it would mean you could check if the the value of each T* is a prime number each time an operation is performed and still respect the standard since you don't touch Ts.
Could you specify where your quotes come from ?

Comment: I think the standard writers know that they cannot use conventional complexity theory because we do not have a fully specified system where we know, for example, the complexity of memory allocation. It's not realistic to pretend that memory can be allocated for a new member of a `list` regardless of the current size of the list; if the list is too large, the allocation will be slow or will fail. Hence, as far as I can see, the committee made a decision to only specify the operations that can be objectively counted and measured. (PS: I have *another* theory on this for another answer.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure `O(n)` means the number of operations is asymptotically proportional to the number of elements.  IE, meta-operations count.  Otherwise it would make no sense to limit lookup to `O(1)`.  Ergo, linked-lists do not qualify.

Comment: This is a very interesting interpretation, but by this logic a `list` could be implemented as a `vector` of pointers too (insertions in to the middle will result in a *single* copy constructor invocation, regardless of list size, and the `O(N)` shuffling of the pointers can be ignored because they are not operations-on-T).

Comment: This is nice language-lawyering (though I'm not going to try to suss out whether it's actually correct or if there's some subtle point in the standard that prohibits this implementation). But it's not useful information in practice, because (1) common implementations don't implement `deque` this way and (2) "cheating" in this way (even if permitted by the standard) when computing algorithmic complexity isn't helpful in writing efficient programs.

Comment: @Kyle Strand, common implementations replace pointers to single Ts with pointers to essentially an fixed arrays of Ts (plus tiny amount of bookkeeping data kept either together with the pointers or with the arrays). They still have the same assymptotic characteristics, only constants typically work out to be more favorable.

Answer (score 18):

> deque = double ended queue

A container which can grow in either direction.

Deque is *typically* implemented as a `vector` of arrays (a linked-list of arrays can't give constant time random access). The size of the arrays is implementation dependent, commonly a constant size in bytes (4096 for libc++, 512 for libstdc++, 16 for MS STL).

This approach means that with any element larger than half the fixed size, the deque effectively becomes a vector of pointers to single element allocations.

Comment: Its not _quite_ vectors internally.  The internal structures can have allocated but unused capacity at the _beginning_ as well as the end

Comment: @MooingDuck: It is implementation defined really.It can be an array of arrays or vector of vectors or anything that can provide the behavior and complexity mandated by the standard.

Comment: @Als: I don't think `array` of anything or `vector` of anything can promise amortized `O(1)` push_front.  The inner of the two structures at least, _must_ be able to have a `O(1)` push_front, which neither an `array` nor a `vector` can guarantee.

Comment: @MooingDuck that requirement is easily met if the first chunk grows top-down rather than bottom-up. Obviously a standard `vector` doesn't do that, but it's a simple enough modification to make it so.

Comment: @ Mooing Duck, Both push_front and push_back can be easily done in amortized O(1) with a single vector structure. It's just a little bit more bookkeeping of a circular buffer, nothing more. Assume you have a regular vector of capacity 1000 with 100 elements in it at positions 0 to 99. Now when a push_Front happens you just push at the end i.e. at position 999, then 998 etc. until the two ends meet. Then you reallocate (with exponential growth to guarantee amortizet constant times) just like you would do with a ordinary vector. So effectively you just need one additional pointer to first el.

Answer (score 11):

I was reading "Data structures and algorithms in C++" by Adam Drozdek, and found this useful. 
HTH.

> A very interesting aspect of STL deque is its implementation. An STL deque is not implemented as a linked list but as an array of pointers to blocks or arrays of data. The number of blocks changes dynamically depending on storage needs, and the size of the array of pointers changes accordingly.

You can notice in the middle is the array of pointers to the data (chunks on the right), and also you can notice that the array in the middle is dynamically changing.

An image is worth a thousand words.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for referring a book. I read the `deque` part and it's quite good.

Comment: @Rick happy to hear that. I remember digging into the deque at some point because I couldn't understand how you can have random access ([]operator) in O(1). Also proving that (push/pop)_(back/front) has amortised O(1) complexity is an interesting 'aha moment'.

Answer (score 6):

While the standard doesn't mandate any particular implementation (only constant-time random access), a deque is usually implemented as a collection of contiguous memory "pages". New pages are allocated as needed, but you still have random access. Unlike `std::vector`, you're not promised that data is stored contiguously, but like vector, insertions in the middle require lots of relocating.

Comment: or deletions in the middle require lots of relocating

Comment: If `insert` requires lots of relocation how does experiment 4 [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5425/An-In-Depth-Study-of-the-STL-Deque-Container) show *staggering* difference between `vector::insert()` and `deque::insert()`?

Comment: @Bula: Perhaps due to miscommunication of the details? The complexity of deque insert is "linear in the number of elements inserted plus the lesser of the distances to the beginning and end of the deque." To feel this cost, you need to insert in the current middle; is that what your benchmark is doing?

Comment: @KerrekSB: article with benchmark was referenced in Konrad answer above. Actually I did not notice comment section of the article below. In thread 'But deque has linear insertion time?' author did mention that he used insertion at position 100 through all tests, which makes results a little more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

`deque` could be implemented as a circular buffer of fixed size array:

- Use circular buffer so we could grow/shrink at both end by adding/removing a fixed sized array with O(1) complexity
- Use fixed sized array so it is easy to calculate the index, hence access via index with two pointer dereferences - also O(1)