# .data() equivalent for std::queue

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, std

My question is simple: **Its possible to obtain a pointer to the underlying storage of a `std::queue` container adapter?**

I'm working on some simulations using SFML for rendering, and I use the `draw()` method of the SFML render target (`sf::RenderTarget`) to draw the entire bunch of data. That method has a C-like interface expecting a pointer to the data and a `std::size_t` with the number of elements to draw.

Since the data is stored in a queue for some purposes, I will be glad if there is some way to get that pointer to the queue underlying storage instead of copying the data to a vector.
I know that `std::queue` adapts the container `std::deque` by default, but I don't know how that circular buffer is implemented and if its data is contiguous (So I can extract a pointer to the data directly).

#### EDIT: Performance

Looking at the answers bellow, let me note that I'm not using `std::deque` because its fancy queue-like interface, but because **I really need fast queueing**. Of course I can use `std::vector`. If performance wasn't the point here I would have used `push_back()`and `erase( begin() )` of vector. But what I need is **fast queueing and a way to move the data of that queue to the render target efficiently**. Of course if the balance *queueing vs effort to draw it* goes to the draw side, I will use `std::vector`.

Comment: IIRC, `std::deque` does not have contiguous storage, but is allocated typically in blocks, with an array of pointers pointing to those blocks.

Comment: No, there is no such member, with reason behind it. The storage provided by the default back-end container, `std::deque<>`, is not mandated by the standard as contiguous. Nor is the implementation mandated as circular, which you also mentioned.

Comment: And if you are curious how a `std::deque<>` is typically implemented, [see this answer to a different question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6292437/1322972) for a common implementation. It spells out nicely why what you seek with a `std::deque<>` back-end simply doesn't exist.

Comment: No one noticed that `std::queue` just wraps the underlying container, so it calls `container.pop_front()` and then it cannot be used with `std::vector`? (n.m. quickly deleted his answer ;) ). If it was that easy, I would currently using `std::vector` and I wouldn't ever asked a question here (Since asking here is the last thing we should do. I ask on SO when I really have no idea about how to continue).

Comment: Honestly, depending on the size of the data you're buffering up for that C API call, I think it likely your copy-then-call approach may very well be your best bet if you truly want fast queuing *and* contiguous data for the call. It at-least-seems to me you would be better off just cutting out the middle man (the queue adapter) use a `deque` straight-way, and keeping your copy-then-call approach. Worthy of benchmarking, I suppose. How much data are we talking about here (per copy)? iterator-based copying (something queue does *not* give but deque *does*), may help significantly.

Comment: I have the same dilemma and an alternative. If you want to avoid copies, you can perhaps detect the queue block at runtime, and render the blocks one by one. It is ugly but I think it is always better than copying. The performance gain will depend on the size of element relative to the size of pointer.  Also there is hope that a future C++ will include the concept of a contiguos iterator and memory blocks. See here  https://stackoverflow.com/q/42851957/225186

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it possible to obtain a pointer to the underlying storage of a
>   std::queue container adapter?

Short answer: No.

`std::queue` requires a `SequenceContainer` type, like `std::deque` or `std::list`. Neither of these guarantee contiguous storage, so there's no concept of a *pointer to the underlying storage*.

If they used contiguous circular buffers, this would either impose a fixed size on the container, or incur large cost (like std::vector can) when the container needs to be resized.

You could look at using a [`boost::circular_buffer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The most intuitive thought would be to use a `std::vector` as the underling container of your `std::queue` to assure contiguous memory and then by taking the address of `std::queue::front` to access the contiguous storage of the wrapped `std::vector`.

However, as [@Blastfurnace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445976/blastfurnace) correctly noted `std::vector` doesn't have a `pop_front` member function and when you were going to call `std::queue::pop` the program would blast.

Also as already mentioned, `std::queue` normally requires as its underlying container, a container like `std::deque` or `std::list`. Due to their structural traits these containers are the most suitable because they can pop efficiently their front element. However, due to its contiguous memory `std::vector` lacks of such versatility.

Also, if use of a container with contiguous memory is something that would boost significantly your application it's better and more straightforward to use a `std::vector`.

However, and for the record, you could also do the following hack in order to circumvent the lack of `std::vector`'s `pop_front` member function. You could define a `class` that inherits from `std::vector` and implement the `pop_front` member function like the example below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template<class T, class Alloc = std::allocator<T>>
class queuevec : public std::vector<T, Alloc> {
public:
  void pop_front() {
   if(!this->empty()) this->erase(this->begin());
  }
};

int main() { 
  std::queue<int, queuevec<int>> Q;

  for(int i(0); i < 10; ++i) Q.push(i);

  Q.pop();

  int *t = &(Q.front());
  std::for_each(t, t + Q.size(), [](int const i){ std::cout << i << " "; });
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e1a07e04a9f9689)

Comment: While that will work, the problem is that the performance of pop_front will be terrible. Even in C++11 there will be a slew of memory moving going on.

Comment: @Roddy, I totally agree with you. IMHO, I think that I cover this aspect in my answer by suggesting the OP to use contiguous memory containers only if there's something significant to gain, and of course always after profiling her/his program.