# is it possible to set the size of the inner array of a stl::deque?

Tags: c++, stl

stl::deque is implemented as an array of arrays;  [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292332/what-really-is-a-deque-in-stl)  explains how it is implemented in most cases; My question is: is it possible to set the size of the inner array (or chunk) ? It seems to be an implementation detail that is impossible to manipulate. Are there implementations that allow to set the size of inner array?

Thanks Pinky for the answer: in libstdc++ (gcc stl) we have

```
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_DEQUE_BUF_SIZE
#define _GLIBCXX_DEQUE_BUF_SIZE 512
#endif

  inline size_t
  __deque_buf_size(size_t __size)
  { return (__size < _GLIBCXX_DEQUE_BUF_SIZE
            ? size_t(_GLIBCXX_DEQUE_BUF_SIZE / __size) : size_t(1)); }
```

So that the size of the inner node is set by defining _GLIBCXX_DEQUE_BUF_SIZE (#define _GLIBCXX_DEQUE_BUF_SIZE 4096 - if you want an inner node of this size) before including the deque header (for stdc++)

__deque_buf_size even has some doxygen documentation, so that this solution is documented (even though it is not covered by the standard).

```
  /**
   *  @brief This function controls the size of memory nodes.
   *  @param  __size  The size of an element.
   *  @return   The number (not byte size) of elements per node.
   *
   *  This function started off as a compiler kludge from SGI, but
   *  seems to be a useful wrapper around a repeated constant
   *  expression.  The @b 512 is tunable (and no other code needs to
   *  change), but no investigation has been done since inheriting the
   *  SGI code.  Touch _GLIBCXX_DEQUE_BUF_SIZE only if you know what
   *  you are doing, however: changing it breaks the binary
   *  compatibility!!
  */
```

Comment: I think it is possible, I have read the source code of SGI STL, the buffer size can be determined by `__deque_buf_size()`.

Comment: the standart says nothing about "inner arrays", so this would be very implementation-specific and will probably rise some compatibility issues, but in the end nothing is really impossible

Comment: Would you mind moving the "answer" part in the question to an actual answer? It's [encouraged by SE rule](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the size of inner array (i.e. blocks or chunks) of `std::deque` cannot be set. The size of inner array depends on an implementation.

I'd like to suggest `sfl::segmented_vector` container from my library which you can find at GitHub: https://github.com/slavenf/sfl-library

This container is similar to `std::deque`. The size of inner arrays (I call them segments) is specified at the compile time as a template parameter.

Answer (score -2):

You can use its ctor:

```
std::deque<int> myDeque (size, defaultValue);
```

Or resize function:

```
std::deque<int> myDeque;
...
myDeque.resize(newSize);
```