# How is deque implemented in c++ stl

Tags: c++, stl, deque

I just wanted to know how deque is implemented and how are the basic operations like **push_front and random access operator are provided in that implementation.**

Comment: From [this `std::deque` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque): "typical implementations use a sequence of individually allocated fixed-size arrays". In short, it's a list of arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What really is a deque in STL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292332/what-really-is-a-deque-in-stl)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if it was implemented as a "list" of arrays, the constant random access wouldn't be possible. Typically it is an array of pointers to arrays with data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just wanted to know how deque is implemented

It's always a good to have an excuse for doing ASCII art:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+                       
| std::deque<int>                                             |                       
|                                                             |                       
|  subarrays:                                                 |                       
| +---------------------------------------------------------+ |                       
| |           |           |           |         |           | |                       
| | int(*)[8] | int(*)[8] | int(*)[8] |int(*)[8]|int(*)[8]  | |                       
| |           |           |           |         |           | |                       
| +---------------------------------------------------------+ |                       
|                        /            \                       |                       
|                       /              \                      |                       
|                      /                \                     |                       
|                     /                  \                    |                       
|                    /                    \                   |                       
|                   /                      \                  |                       
|                  /                        \                 |                       
|                 /                          \                |                       
|                -                            -               |                       
|               +------------------------------+              |                       
|               | ?, ?, 42, 43, 50, ?, ?, ?, ? |              |                       
|               +------------------------------+              |                       
|                                                             |
| additional state:                                           |                       
|                                                             |                       
| - pointer to begin of the subarrays                         |                       
| - current capacity and size                                 |                       
| - pointer to current begin and end                          |                       
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

> how are the basic operations like `push_front` and random access operator are provided in that implementation?

First, `std::deque::push_front`, from libcxx:

```
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
void
deque<_Tp, _Allocator>::push_front(const value_type& __v)
{
    allocator_type& __a = __base::__alloc();
    if (__front_spare() == 0)
        __add_front_capacity();
    __alloc_traits::construct(__a, _VSTD::addressof(*--__base::begin()), __v);
    --__base::__start_;
    ++__base::size();
}
```

This obviously checks whether the memory already allocated at the front can hold an additional element. If not, it allocates. Then, the main work is shifted to the iterator: `_VSTD::addressof(*--__base::begin())` goes one location before the current front element of the container, and this address is passed to the allocator to construct a new element in place by copying `v` (the default allocator will definitely do a placement-`new`).

Now random access. Again from libcxx, `std::deque::operator[]` (the non-`const` version) is

```
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
inline
typename deque<_Tp, _Allocator>::reference
deque<_Tp, _Allocator>::operator[](size_type __i) _NOEXCEPT
{
    size_type __p = __base::__start_ + __i;
    return *(*(__base::__map_.begin() + __p / __base::__block_size) + __p % __base::__block_size);
}
```

This pretty much computes an index relative to some start index, and then determines the subarray and the index relative to the start of the subarray. `__base::__block_size` should be the size of one subarray here.

Comment: Any idea what is the purpose of the subarrays rather than using just a single array?

Comment: It guarantees that iterators/references into the data structure aren't invalidated when adding/removing elements. The standard imposes this behaviour.

Comment: What am I missing then? How do the subarrays solve it? If I just have a single resizable array with pointers to the data, they don't invalidate the references either.

Comment: They do. If you search for "C++ vector iterator invalidation" or something similar you'll quickly find an explanation why this happens.

Comment: @QwertYuiop When dynamic array runs out of capacity, the whole contiguous block must be reallocated, moving the elements to a new location in memory. When deque runs out of capacity, it is enough to allocate a new block and prepend/append it to existing ones.

Comment: @marski, when the dynamic array allocates a new block and copies the pointers from the old block to the new block, the data itself is still in the same place, so pointers to them are not invalidated.

Comment: @QwertYuiop Dynamic array holds values not pointers to values. If you copy a value to a different block, it lives under a different address.

Comment: @marski, yeah so my comment was that if you used a vector of pointers instead, you wouldn't invalidate references either. So where do the subarrays come in, why are they needed?

Comment: @QwertYuiop Storing pointers to *single* elements would defeat the biggest advantage of the array: memory locality of a contiguous memory block. You can look at chunked design as storing pointers to *multiple* contiguous elements to get a balanced compromise. Many data structures, such as B-trees, tries and ropes use a similar principle. In a similar manner AoSoA is a compromise between AoS and SoA.