# Why the exception is thrown on std::deque.erase()?

Tags: c++, c++11

This throws when trying to remove element from `deque` via iterator. The error is "can not seek value-initialized iterator" using VS2017. I wonder why this is happening, isn't `std::deque` a doubly linked list that does not invalidate iterators on `push_front()` / `push_back()`?

```
class deque2 {
public:
    bool enqueue(int val) {
        if (mp.find(val) != mp.end()) {
            return false;
        }
        dq.push_front(val);
        mp[val] = dq.begin();
        return true;
    }

    int dequeue() {
        if (dq.size() == 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        int res = dq.back();
        mp.erase(res);
        dq.pop_back();
        return res;
    }

    void erase(int val) {
        auto it = mp.find(val);
        if (it != mp.end()) {
            dq.erase(it->second); // exception 
            mp.erase(val);
        }
    }
private:
    deque<int> dq;
    unordered_map<int, deque<int>::iterator> mp;
};
```

Comment: "isn't std::deque a doubly linked list" no it is not. Why would somebody put the same container with different names in the library?

Comment: Note that `return -1;` is probably not a good error handling solution. `deque2` can contain that value in its normal use.

Comment: Can you please provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux actually they do https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/push_back

Comment: sorry for being dumb. <list> should have been used here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292332/what-really-is-a-deque-in-stl has the internal explanation how deque works in STL under the hood

Comment: @Slava Thanks, I guess I was thinking of pointers to elements.

Answer (score 2):

> isn't std::deque a doubly linked list

No it is not. As stated in [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)

> std::deque (double-ended queue) is an indexed sequence container that allows fast insertion and deletion at both its beginning and its end. In addition, insertion and deletion at either end of a deque never invalidates **pointers or references** to the rest of the elements.

emphasis is mine. Note that it says that pointer or references not invalidated, not iterators. And documentations on [std::deque::push_front()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/push_front) clearly says so:

> All iterators, including the past-the-end iterator, are invalidated. No references are invalidated.

As for the logic you are trying to implement I would recommend to use `boost::multi_index` as it allows single container with different access criteria and you do not have to maintain 2 containers in sync. Documentation can be found [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)